# TypeError when including a clone of a Module in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module, include

I'm testing a Module that has a state. Currently I restore that state after each testcase. Instead I would like to use a throwaway clone of the module.

Consider the following simple example:

```
module MyModule; end
clone = MyModule.clone
clone.class # => Module
clone.class == MyModule.class # => true
class MyClass
  include clone # => TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
end
```

Why doesn't this work? Is there a way to achieve what I'm aiming for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the scope of `clone` as a local variable does not go inside the class body of `MyClass`. There, `clone` is interpreted as a method applied to `self`. Hence, your last three lines are equivalent to:

```
class MyClass
  include MyClass.clone
end
```

And since `MyClass` is a class, so is its clone `MyClass.clone`. You cannot include a class.